# Stacking overset and superscript

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I want to write this expression [image].

My attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{bm,amsmath,physics,amssymb,mathrsfs,dsfont}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\title{Test}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
Neither $\det(\tall {\overset{0}{\sigma^{AB}}}) $ nor $\det(\tall {\overset{0}{\sigma}}^{AB})$ works.

\end{document}
```

[image]
My attempt thus leaves a lot desired.

How can I format it like shown above?

Answer (score 1):

Set the argument for the determinant using `\overset`, and set the exponent `AB` separate from that using `\vphantom{\sigma}^{AB}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

$\det \overset{(0)}{\sigma} \vphantom{\sigma}^{AB} \neq 0$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `accents`. In this particular case, a small space needs to be added at the left.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,accents}

\newcommand{\osigma}[1]{\,\accentset{(#1)}{\sigma}}

\begin{document}

$\det(\osigma{0}^{AB})$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

$\det\left( {\overset{0}{\sigma^{AB}}}\right)$

$\det\left( {\overset{0}{\sigma}}^{AB}\right) $ 

\end{document}
```

[image]